# How to give a null default parameter in an xml routing file

Tags: symfony

**This code** dumps the correct `$id` variable of type `null`:

```php
/**
 * Show user
 *
 * @Route("/show/{id}", name="acme_user_show", defaults={"id"=null}, requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 */
public function showUserAction($id = null)
{
    var_dump($id);
}
```

**whereas** the following code gives an `$id` variable of type `string`: `string(4) "null"`

```php
/**
 * Show user
 *
 */
public function showUserAction($id = null)
{
    var_dump($id);
}
```

**routing.xml**

```php
<route id="acme_user_show" pattern="/show/{id}">
    <default key="_controller">AcmeUserBundle:User:show</default>
    <default key="id">null</default>
    <requirement key="id">\d+</requirement>
</route>
```

I would assume the 2 to give similar results, is this normal? How would one give a default null value in xml?

---

- I visit the `/showUser` path to test if `$id` variable is null.
- I also tried `<default key="id" />` instead of `<default key="id">null</default>` => no success

Comment: What happends when you just remove the complete `default[key=id]` element from your XML?

Comment: I get a 404: `No route found for "GET /showUser"` because there is no default value :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to clarify Patt's answer, this was fixed, the correct way to specify it is like this:

```
 <default key="threadId" xsi:nil="true" />
```

So full route specification in your case would be like this:

```
<route id="acme_user_show" pattern="/show/{id}">
    <default key="_controller">AcmeUserBundle:User:show</default>
    <default key="id" xsi:nil="true" />
    <requirement key="id">\d+</requirement>
</route>
```

Comment: Well done! I unaccepted my answer to accept yours. I am glad this is finally fixed!

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not implemented in xml  (yet). See this [bug report](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7335).

> @Aitboudad: The routing xml loader does not support null value, the correct way to
>   represent null xml elements is xsi:nil="true".